# Why document.write('\ud83d\ude00') can output a emoji in HTML which is UTF-8 charset?

Tags: javascript, unicode, utf-8, interpreter, emoji

This is html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>emoji</title>
</head>
<body>
    \ud83d\ude00
    <script>
        var string = '\ud83d\ude00';
        document.write(string);
        console.log(string);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The unicode '\ud83d\ude00' in body tag can't show as a emoji but a string. But '\ud83d\ude00' can show as a emoji by document.write() and console.log() even thought the document charset is UTF-8.  Why?

Comment: Why are you even using `document.write`? Don't do that.

Comment: Javascript uses UTF-16 internally. Independent of what your HTML or even the JS source said.

Answer (score 1):

The UTF-8 in the meta header just says how to read the **text** of the HTML response, it doesn't put the actual DOM document into some kind of mode that makes the document itself UTF-8.

As for why your string works: A JavaScript string is [a series of UTF-16 code units](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-language-types-string-type). So `'\ud83d\ude00'` defines the emoji at the JavaScript level. Then you use `document.write` to write that string out to the document. At that point, you're dealing with a live document, not the source text that you said was in UTF-8.

If you want to include the emoji in the document directly, rather than via `document.write`, just paste it into the document; your editor will output the appropriate UTF-8 sequence for it if you save the file as UTF-8 (which you need to, because you've told the browser that's the encoding you're using).

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It is very useful for me.

Answer (score 1):

Please just consider this an addition to T.J. Crowder's answer - I don't have 50 rep so couldn't add as a comment :(

You're escaping in html incorrectly, in Javascript backslashes (**\**) are used to escape but in HTML escaping is achieved by prefixing with ampersand (**&**) and suffixing with a semicolon (**;**).

You can use HTML numeric character references:

```html
<div>decimal:  &#128512;</div>
<div>hex:      &#x1f600;</div>
```

And [here is](http://character-code.com/emoticons-html-codes.php) a good reference for emoji HTML codes.

Disclaimer: I have no affiliation with the website

Comment: Thanks T.J I've removed the incorrect statement now. Plus even if it was correct its the kind of sentence that adds nothing to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious reason would be that `\ud83d\ude00` are no escape sequences in HTML test.

Using [HTML entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) instead it should work:

```html
\ud83d\ude00
&#xd83d;&#xde00;
&#x1f600;
```